# Cockpit terminal vs PuTTY terminal - "Command Not Found" in Cockpit

Tags: centos, python

Recently I enabled Cockpit on a newly built Centos server(7.6).  I also installed Python 3.7.4 on the same server (using `make altinstall`).

Here's the weird thing.

When I call Python on a PuTTY terminal, i.e, `python3.7 -V`, it returns the expected result: `Python 3.7.4`

When I call Python on the Cockpit terminal (using the same credentials), it returns a `bash: python3.7: command not found...`

This is using the same login details.

What am I missing?

Cheers

Please forgive me if there is an obvious answer to this.  I am very new (or more to the point, relearning) to Linux.

Comment: I guess the `PATH` is different between the two. To check, `echo "$PATH"` in both and compare.

Comment: @mosvy - Today I learnt!  OK, yes, that is the difference.  Thanks.  Now I know what at least to look at.  Hopefully I can understand these nuances.  I assume I need to add transportable variables to `~/.bashrc` , or is there something else I need to do?